# Magento changes file permission of cron.sh after backup

Tags: magento, permissions, cron, backup

If I do a **backup magento** always **changes the file permission** of the **cron.sh to 644** and the cron daemon sends me an error message "`/bin/sh: /magento/cron.sh: Permission denied`". The error is correct because the user doing the cronjob hasn't permission to execute. It will only work if the permission is at least 744.

Is there a possibility to set the file permission automatically correct? In future the backup will be part of the cronjob and will take place in the night so I need to fix this issue.